# Selenium with Chromedriver stops when alert appears

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm still working on automated website testing with Selenium using Chromedriver.

Now we have some accounts we want to log into for a test, these accounts after login immediately receive a browser alert. At this point Chromedriver throws an UnexpectedAlertException and quits. Thus further testing is impossible for now since we get various Alerts on our pages.

The weird thing is that with some other pages we are testing, this does not happen, and instead the tests just continue, although we also receive the same alert.

What makes an alert 'unexpected' for Chromedriver and is there a way to stop it crashing our tests?

Comment: what language are you using with selenium?

Comment: PHP (with Mink)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the capapibility UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE

Comment: I've done that now, but Chromedriver still throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the Mink implementation of the Selenium 2 driver supports alerts and confirmation prompts: https://github.com/minkphp/Mink/issues/158#issuecomment-230479602

The above link might be able to provide you with a workaround for Mink.

For PHPUnit selenium, if you can use that instead or for anyone else coming across this question, you can use the `dismissAlert()`, `acceptAlert()` and `alertText()` functions which have been implemented:

```
// Log in, etc
$this->assertEquals('Your alert text', $this->alertText());
$this->acceptAlert(); // or $this->dismissAlert();
```

Comment: We already have a similar solution which works fine on about one half of our websites, but on the other the Exception occurs as soon as the Alert opens. However it all just seems to be the same browser alert.